# Contar numero de veces que se repite el valor de una key de n diccionarios dentro de una lista

Tags: c#, visual-studio

¿ Mediante programación funcional como puedo saber cuantas veces ser repite el valor de una key de n diccionarios dentro de una lista ?

Tengo lo siguiente:

```
List<Object> miLista = new List<Object>();
Dictionary<string, object> items = new Dictionary<string, object>();


items.Add("objetoId","01");
items.Add("nombre","manzana");
miLista.Add(new Dictionary<string,object>() { {"objetoId",items["objetoId"]}, {"nombre",items["nombre"]} });
items.Clear();
items.Add("objetoId","02");
items.Add("nombre","manzana");
miLista.Add(new Dictionary<string,object>() { {"objetoId",items["objetoId"]}, {"nombre",items["nombre"]} });
items.Clear();
items.Add("objetoId","03");
items.Add("nombre","pera");
miLista.Add(new Dictionary<string,object>() { {"objetoId",items["objetoId"]}, {"nombre",items["nombre"]} });
```

Ejemplo,

Para Key = "objetoId" 
    El valor "01" se repite 1 vez.
    El valor "02" se repite 1 vez.
    El valor "03" se repite 1 vez.

Para Key = "nombre"
    El valor "manzana" se repite 2 veces.
    El valor "pera" se repite 1 vez.

Comment: porque dices "programación funcional" ? donde estas programando de esta forma, no sera programacion orientada a objetos?

Comment: para que sirve la variable `items` si en definitiva despues tomas el valor simple y lo pones en el diccionario que tiene la lista

Comment: Creo que estas equivocando el uso de las List<> y Dictionary<> porque no se aplica como lo estas haciendo. con solo usar el Dictionary<> alcanza y sobra con lo que estas planteando. Si quieres puedo poner un ejemplo como respuesta en todo caso sino te convence lo elimino

Comment: @LeandroTuttini el uso de List lo hago porque puedo tener dentro cualquier objeto. En este caso solo lo he rellando de Diccionarios pero podría llenar una celda del List con  un Diccionario, otra celda con un  string,etc. Para el ejemplo ya me basta que funcione con Diccionarios. La variable ítems es para que se graben los datos en la lista por valor y no por referencia ya que si pongo el ítem directamente en la Lista conservaría  la referencia y todas las posiciones del List apuntarían a la misma posision y me mostraría los mismos valores. Cualquier ejemplo que pongas me ayudara ! Gracias

Comment: @LeandroTuttini cuando digo programación funcional para resumirlo es usando Foreach, Map, Filter, Find, Where...

Comment: ok pero si vas a tener cualquier objeto porque despues haces `{"objetoId",items["objetoId"]}` esto invalida el uso del `Dictionary<>` porque es lo mismo que hicieras `{"objetoId", "01"}`, por eso comento que la una de las dos esta de mas o no se aplica como lo estas pensando

Comment: el {"objetoId",items["objetoId"]}  además lo pongo porque estaba pensado a la hora de poner este código dentro de un bucle.. En vez de escribirlo 3 veces.. puedo tener n veces

Comment: Es decir los datos los cojo de un diccionario, podría cogerlos de un webservice,  de un dataset, etc... el items lo he creado para rellenar mi Lista

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por el problem que planteas se puede resolver facilmente solo con un `Dictionary<>` ya que solo necesitas la key que agrupe los datos, estando la lista definida para los valores, algo como ser:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> dic = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

List<string> datos1 = new List<string>() {"01", "02", "03"}
dic.Add("objetoId", datos1);

List<string> datos2 = new List<string>() {"manzana", "manzana", "pera"}
dic.Add("nombre", datos2);
```

entonces solo iteras las keys

```
foreach(var keyvalue in dic)
{
   var query = from item in keyvalue.Value  //recuerda que Value es una List<string>
               group item by item into g
               select new {
                 key = g.Key,
                 cantidad = g.Count
               };
   string cadena = "";
   foreach(var item in query)
   {
     cadena += string.Format("El valor {0} se repite {1} veces.", item.key, item.cantidad);
   }
   Console.WriteLine("Para key: {0} {1} ", keyvalue.key, cadena)
}
```

La idea es iterar las keys del diccionario y agrupar usando `linq` la lista que tiene dentro.

---

Igualmente mas alla de la solucion anterior, perticularmente no la aplicaria sino que iria a algo mas `orientado a objetos`.

Crearia una clase como ser

```
public class Articulo
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string Nombre {get;set;}
}
```

Tendrias una lista del tipo

```
List<Articulo> articulos = new List<Articulo>();

articulos.Add(new Articulo(){ Id = 1, Nombre = "manazana" });
articulos.Add(new Articulo(){ Id = 2, Nombre = "manazana" });
articulos.Add(new Articulo(){ Id = 3, Nombre = "pera" });
```

Puede iterarlo mas facil, previo agrupado usando `linq`

```
var query = from item in articulos
               group item by item.Nombre into g
               select new {
                 Id = g.First().Id,
                 Nombre = g.Key,
                 Cantidad = g.Count
               };

foreach(var item in query)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Para la key {0} El valor {1} se repite {2} veces.", item.Id, item.Nombre, item.Cantidad)
}
```

Personalmente me gusta mas usar `class` para definir la entidad qur recibira los datos, en lugar de `Dictionary<>` ya en este caso no estas asociando el `objetId` con el `nombre` que serian dos propiedades

Comment: Perfecto , la segunda solución con la clase es la que mejor se adapta a mis necesidades. Muchas Gracias !

Comment: En Cantidad el IDE de Visual Studio me escribe lo siguiente " No se puede asignar grupo de métodos a una propiedad de tipo anónimo "

Comment: Quizas me falto usar las `()` en el `Count` en linq `Cantidad = g.Count()`

Comment: Correcto faltaba las (). Aunque haría falta un filtro para que no me repitiera las coincidencias de value que ya ha buscado. Por ejemplo manzana me repite 2 veces que hay 2 coincidencias. Pero bien con esta idea que me planteastes mas o menos ya me sirve

Comment: el tema es que agrupas por nombre, por lo tanto para "manzana" deberias mostrar dos Ids, lo que propuse es una idea pero quizas no seria bueno usar First() con el id sino tener la lista de los que repiten para el nombre